# Is it possible to time out a cucumber.js step defintion

Tags: javascript, cucumber, cucumberjs

In cucumber.js, I define a step, something like:

```
this.When(/^I call getCollections$/, function(callback) {

    this.repo.getCollections( function( err, results ) {

        this.results = results;
        callback( err );

    }.bind( this ) );

});
```

But if the call to `this.repo.getColections` never calls back my function, then `callback` will never execute, and cucumber.js immediately exits with a normal exit code.

Is there a way to get cucumber.js to fail if callback is never called?

Answer (score 1):

Something along those lines should do the trick:

```
this.Given(/^blah$/, function (callback) {
  var failed = false;
  var timeout = setTimeout(function () {
    callback(new Error("Timed out"));
  }, 500);

  doSomethingThatMightNeverCallback(function (err) {
    if (!failed) {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      callback(err);
    }
  });
});
```

You can easily redefine Cucumber's Given/When/Then:

```
var cucumber = this;
var Given = When = Then = defineStep;
function defineStep (name, handler) {
  cucumber.defineStep(name, function () {
    var world = this;
    var args = Array.prototype.splice.call(arguments, 0);
    var callback = args.pop();

    var failed = false;
    var timeout = setTimeout(function () {
      callback(new Error("Timed out"));
    }, 500);

    args.push(function (err) {
      if (!failed) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        callback(err);
      }
    });
    handler.apply(world, args);
  });
}
```

Then define your step definitions with `Given()`, `When()` and `Then()` instead of `this.Given()`, etc.:

```
Given(/^foo$/, function (callback) {
  setTimeout(callback, 400); // this will pass
});

Given(/^bar$/, function (callback) {
  setTimeout(callback, 500); // this will fail
});

When(/^baz$/, function (callback) {
  doYourStuff(callback);
});
```

I got the following scenario failing on step 2, as expected:

```
Feature: Baz

  Scenario:
    Given foo
    And bar
```

The output:

```
cucumber.js test.feature 
.F

(::) failed steps (::)

Error: Timed out
    at null._onTimeout (/Users/jbpros/tmp/abc/code.js:13:18)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)

Failing scenarios:
/Users/jbpros/tmp/abc/test.feature:3 # Scenario: 

1 scenario (1 failed)
2 steps (1 failed, 1 passed)
```

HTH,

- Julien.

Comment: When you're writing code in Node, almost everything is a callback, and a central part of testing is to establish that the code successfully calls back on every branch. I shouldn't have to write this code around every When step to ensure that. And it feels wrong that I can't use the built in Given When Then facility. Is this something that I could redefine in a custom World constructor, so that it's hidden away?

Comment: The proposed solution does use the built-in Given/When/Then. It just wraps it into another function that handles timeout the way you want. Why it's not built in is because we can't tell what are everyone's needs regarding lost callbacks. The callback issue is well known (https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/issues/27) and there is no global-scale solution atm. Timeouts might be the perfect approach for your project, but it's not the case for everyone. An "timeout" plugin for Cucumber could be helpful though and I'm thinking about releasing such a thing.

Comment: To answer your question: no you can't redefine Given/When/Then on the World for the simple reason that Worlds are instantiated well after step definitions are loaded. That being said, it's pretty easy to "hide" the wrapper above in its own module and load that nicely in your step definitions.

Comment: In what situation would a "lost" callback _not_ be a reason to fail the step?

Comment: It *is* definitely a good reason to fail a step. There's just no straightforward way of telling when a callback is lost in JavaScript, afaik.

Comment: Perhaps a default of timeout after 1 second on a step would be sensible. Overrideable if necessary?

Comment: Even if timing out by default is not desired, surely it can't be right for cucumber.js to just exit with a normal exit code? That means there's no way for a CI server to tell that the run failed to complete.

Comment: You're absolutely right about the exit code. This has to be sorted out. Feel free to join the discussion on the GitHub issue.

Comment: got a link? can't see it looking through the issue list.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've ended up doing:

In a module utils.js, I expose a function

```
function specifyTimeout( scenario, timeout ) {

    scenario.Before( function( callback ) {

        scenario.timeout = setTimeout( function() { throw new Error("Timed out"); }, 500 );
        callback();

    } );

    scenario.After( function( callback ) {

        clearTimeout( scenario.timeout );
        callback();

    } );

}
```

then at the top of my step definitions, I just do:

```
module.exports = function() {

    utils.specifyTimeout( this, 500 );
    . . .
```